# No Class Def Found error

Tags: java, exception, noclassdeffounderror

I wrote the following class in NetBeans and ran it successfully. But when I uploaded it to the IEEE moshack server where I participated for the IEEE Extreme competition.

It says that my program gives a run-time error. Can you please tell me why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class BloomFilter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int[] a = new int[26];
        for (int b : a) {
            b = 0;
        }


        String s = sc.nextLine();
       String s1 = sc.nextLine();


        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) >= 65 && s.charAt(i) <= 90) {

                int p = s.charAt(i) - 65;

                a[p] = 1;

            }

            if ((s.charAt(i) >= 97 && s.charAt(i) <= 122)) {

                int p = s.charAt(i) - 97;

                a[p] = 1;
            }
        }

        String[] tokens = s1.split("[^a-zA-Z]");
        int totWords = 0;

        for (String s2 : tokens) {
            s2.toLowerCase();
            totWords++;
            for (int j = 0; j < s2.length(); j++) {
                if (a[s2.charAt(j) - 97] == 0) {
                    totWords--;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

        System.out.print(totWords);


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you spell out words like "u"?  And maybe post the stack trace so we'll know what class can't be found.  It's a CLASSPATH issue, of course.  NetBeans lets you remain ignorant about how CLASSPATH works, which is a shame.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: BloomFilter/class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BloomFilter.class
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: BloomFilter.class
`

Comment: Please edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 2):

Older versions of DomJudge for example required that Java classes are named `Main`; more recent versions are better in that regard, but maybe a similar restriction is in place where you uploaded it.

Check the error message for the class name Java expected and try renaming your class (and the file, of course).

**EDIT:** Apparently you tried running it with `java BloomFilter.class` instead of `java BloomFilter`. I doubt this is a problem with the submission system, though (such things are spotted earlier, generally), so maybe there is a place somewhere where you give the command to run.